# How to send a redirect parameter using HttpServletResponse setHeader() from controller to a target HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

I am sending a login request of User ID and User Password from an HTML Login screen using POST to a SpringMVC REST controller which then redirects to a default HTML landing page (upon successful login) AND PASSES an additional parameter, called "token", which I do not want displayed in the URL address bar for security reasons so I would like to include it in the HTTP Header during the redirect from the controller to the redirected HTML target landing page (so that it does not display in the URL address bar as a parameter e.g. ?token=123) and then I will retrieve it in the target HTML landing page using getHeader().

My controller code to handle the login parameters is as follows:

UserController.java

```
        @ResponseBody
        @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public void loginUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("txtUserName") String usrName, @RequestParam("txtUserPassword") String password, HttpSession session, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {

        try {
        
                List<User> currentUsers = service.getUsersByUserName(usrName);
                
                
                String strCurrentUserRole = currentUsers.get(0).getUserRole();
                String strCurrentUserPassword = currentUsers.get(0).getUserPassword();
                
                
                if(strCurrentUserPassword.equals(password))
                {
                
                    if(strCurrentUserRole.equals("ADMIN"))
                        {
                        response.setHeader("token", "123");
                        String redirectURL = response.encodeRedirectURL("/defaultLandingPage.html");
                        response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);                     
                        request.getRequestDispatcher(redirectURL).include(request, response);
                        }
```

The problem is, I do get the token header key and its value ("123") but it is in the controller but not in the targeted HTML (defaultLandingPage.html). I would like to retrieve the header "token" and its value in my target HTML page using :

targetLandingPage.html:

```
<html>

<script>
    function retrieveTokenHeader() {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    alert('myHeaders.get(token) : ' + myHeaders.get('token'));
    }
</script>

<body onload="retrieveTokenHeader()">
</body>

</html>
```

which at the moment is returning null.

Why is the header "token" stuck at my controller and not passed on to my target redirect HTML page? How do I pass on or include the "token":"123" header parameter in my target HTML page rather than the controller so that it can be retrieved and read there?

Comment: I don't think you have access to the response headers when the browser makes a POST request. To retrieve the token you can use a Set-Cookie header instead, so JS can read the token from the cookies.

Comment: Yes, you are right Chris! I've upvoted and using the cookies now.